# Docker SDK/API How to assign IP to container in python?

Tags: python, docker, api, sdk

How do I write the ip parameter of the following command using docker sdk in python? I need the --ip parameter to be written in python in this run command

```
docker run -p 2035:2035 -p 5026:5026/udp -p 5307:5307 -p 6233:6233 -p 6343:6343 -p 3140:3140 -p 8181:8181 -p 221:22 --privileged=true --restart=always --net=mynetwork --ip=172.22.5.361 --hostname mycont --name mycont /root/Applications/script/start.sh
```

This is the part I wrote. But IP parameter is not found in docker sdk manual. That's why I'm stuck here.

```
client = docker.from_env()
imageTag = input("image tag: ")
client.containers.run('193.163.23.29:5001/myway/myways:'+imageTag, detach=True, ports={2035:2035,'5026/udp':5026,5307:5307,6233:6233,6343:6343,3140:3140,8181:8181,22:221},restart_policy={"Name": "always"}, network='mynetwork', hostname='mycont', name='mycont', command='/root/Applications/script/start.sh')
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do here is to ignore this option, and also remove it from the `docker run` invocation.  You almost never need the container-private IP address for anything and it's almost never necessary to manually set it.  It's not usable in a wide variety of common situations, and you can almost always either use Docker networking (between containers) or a published port instead.

---

This having been said: this is possible using the [low-level API](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#docker.api.container.ContainerApiMixin.create_container).  This returns a container ID and not a `Container` object.  This creates the container but does not start it, so you'll have to do that step separately.

```py
container = client.api.create_container(
  '193.163.23.29:5001/myway/myways:'+imageTag,
  networking_config=client.api.create_networking_config({
    'mynetwork': client.api.create_endpoint_config(
      ipv4_address='172.22.5.36'
    )
  }),
  ...
)
client.api.start(container['Id'])
```

Several other options are different, and this follows the [REST API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.41/#operation/ContainerCreate)'s option layout more than idiomatic Python.